# Why I get android-java-gradle-error even they are compatible versions?

Tags: java, android, flutter, gradle

I'm using jdk17 and gradle 7.6.1 which can compatible, (jdk17 supports upper than gradle7.3) but I still get

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':gradle:compileGroovy'.
> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit 'C:\src\flutter\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\src\main\groovy\app_plugin_loader.groovy' Unsupported class file major version 65     

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 9s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                             10.6s

┌─ Flutter Fix ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ [!] Your project's Gradle version is incompatible with the Java version that Flutter is using for Gradle. │
│                                                                                                           │
│ To fix this issue, consult the migration guide at docs.flutter.dev/go/android-java-gradle-error.          │
└───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

this error when I run flutter whether I clicked vscode's run button or typed 'run flutter' on terminal of vscode.

but when I typed '.\gradlew build' and '.\gradlew installDebug' in terminal of vscode, it worked. should I type above commands everytime? or is there anyway to solve this problem?

- jdk version

```
java version "17.0.10" 2024-01-16 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17.0.10+11-LTS-240)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.10+11-LTS-240, mixed mode, sharing)
```

- codes in gradle-wrapper properties

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.6.1-bin.zip
networkTimeout=10000
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

(btw, I doesn't use emulator because my laptop performence is bad, so I don't have android studio - flutter doctor always said about this but I ignore that everytime ;)  -  and I just use my second phone to check apps)

sorry for bad english and thank you for your helps :)